# Was there some language(s) in which its logical operators returning a true or false only?

Tags: logical-operator

I remember in the past, for some languages which I can't remember, be it Fortran, Pascal, or Scheme, a logical operator

```
2 || 3
```

will always return a boolean value.

But in the modern languages: JavaScript, Ruby, Python2, they all return `2`.

I want to be careful about: which common languages return strictly true / false, and which common languages return the last evaluated value?

Answer (score 3):

The C Language:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf(2||3 ? "true\n" : "false\n");

    return 0;
}
```

In C, zero is interpreted to be `false`.  Any other value is interpreted to be `true`.

That's why things like

```
while(x) { }
```

work properly, if x decrements towards zero.  This is considered idiomatic C.

Working example in ideone: https://ideone.com/1ZFydA

Comment: A better example would be `printf("%d", 2||3);`, which prints 1 for true (or 0 for false).

Comment: You're completely right with C only returning "true" `1` or "false" `0` (not `true` nor `false`, btw, though there's `_Bool` ... it's really an `int`, even in C11) ... but your examples also would work e.g. in Common Lisp where everything except `nil` is considered "truthy".

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ I guess? Though they use `1` and `0` instead of `true` and `false`...

Most dynamic languages will return `2` because they can and because it's useful. No in this particular case, but when you want to set a default value for some variable:

```
some_variable = setting or default_value
```

instead of

```
if setting:
    some_variable = setting
else:
    some_variable = default_value
```

Static languages, on the other hand, tend to disallow `2 || 3` altogether, because they have learned that treating everything as booleans is bug-prune.

The only language I know(there may be others) where `2 || 3` yields `true`(as opposed to `1`) is [D](http://dlang.org/), a static language that has a proper `bool` type but still allows numbers(or pointers) to be treated as booleans: https://dpaste.dzfl.pl/b40659f1ed1c. Because it's static it can not return `2`(or it would not allow `2 || true`), so it has to convert it to the "least common denominator" - a boolean, `true`.

Comment: Please don't treat C and C++ as one language. They're not. This is important in this context because in C++ `2 || 3` actually evaluates to `true` (and not to `1`).

Comment: @DanielJour http://cpp.sh/9z4h

Comment: Yes, it *prints* as 1. But it's a `bool`, see: http://ideone.com/K7FLpG

Answer (score 1):

In many (statically) typed languages, this would simply be a type error, e.g.

## Scala

```scala
2 || 3
// <console>:12: error: value || is not a member of Int
//        2 || 3
//          ^
```

## Haskell

```haskell
2 || 3
-- <interactive>:1:1: error:
--     • No instance for (Num Bool) arising from the literal ‘2’
--     • In the first argument of ‘(||)’, namely ‘2’
--       In the expression: 2 || 3
--       In an equation for ‘it’: it = 2 || 3
```

## F♯

```fsharp
2 || 3;;
//   2 || 3;;
//   ^
// 
// stdin(1,1): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
//     'bool'    
// but here has type
//     'int'
```

## C♯

```csharp
2 || 3;
// (1,1): error CS0019: Operator `||' cannot be applied to operands of type `int' and `int'
```

## Java

```java
2 || 3
// error: bad operand types for binary operator '||'
//     2 || 3
//       ^
//   first type:  int
//   second type: int
// 1 error
```

Since boolean operators can only be applied to boolean operands, they naturally evaluate to boolean values.

In languages where it *isn't* a type error, evaluating to one of the operands conveys strictly more information than evaluating to a boolean value, so why not do it that way?

The only exception I can think of, is the already mentioned D language.

Comment: yes, I use it too... such as `s = person.name || ""` so that if `person.name` is `null`, then set it to the empty string... just that when I see `undefined || 0` then I forgot and thought about the boolean value

Comment: or maybe the C language can be viewed as such, if `2 || 3` is `1`, and is sort of a `true` representation of the boolean value `true`, when C doesn't have boolean type

Comment: And how is this different from Ruby? In Ruby, `2 || 3` evaluates to `2`, which is a true value.

Comment: right, but it does give back the operand, versus in C, it doesn't give you back the operand.  This is tricky only in interview questions (or in exams), when they ask you what is printed: `console.log(undefined || 0)`